# How to disable this incorrect lint warning for a single code block?

Tags: android, lint, android-lint

I have a small code which gives an incorrect lint warning:

```
int myfunc(@Nullable valStr) {
    int val = -1;
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(valStr)) {
        try {
            val = valStr.startsWith("1-"); //<== lint warning here : NullPointerException
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    return val;
}
```

This code gives lint warning that says `valStr` may be `null` which is impossible because I have checked `valStr` with `TextUtils.isEmpty()`. How I can disable this warning for the `if` block statement?I don't want to disable it for the whole function with `@SuppressLint`.

Comment: Check this out: [How to tell IDEA/Studio that the null check has been done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302211/how-to-tell-idea-studio-that-the-null-check-has-been-done/53652618#53652618) and [TextUtils.isEmpty checks for null but lint doesn't recognise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55635564/textutils-isempty-checks-for-null-but-lint-doesnt-recognise)

Answer (score 2):

The simple code comment for disabling the warning is:

```
//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
```

This on top of the if-statement should switch off the warning only at that place.

In the example, this would be:

```
int myfunc(@Nullable valStr) {
    int val = -1;

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(valStr)) {
        try {
            val = valStr.startsWith("1-"); //<== lint warning here : NullPointerException
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    return val;
}
```

Comment: it seems this comment does not work in android studio. as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340056/noinspection-keyword-list-in-android-studio

Comment: You should mention the exact warning type, e.g.: `//noinspection LaunchActivityFromNotification` to suppress the warning inspection.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `!TextUtils.isEmpty(valStr)` do `valStr != null`. This way lint will know that you have checked the value for `null`.

Alternatively you could use `assert` like this:  `assertNotNull(valStr)`

Comment: This method is obvious. But when `TextUtil.isEmpty()` is doing both, I prefer to use that function.

Comment: You actually don't have to check if it's empty, since startsWith will return -1 if there is no match in the not null string.

Comment: The code here is just a simple code to show the warning. My real code is more complex which needs to be run when it is not empty or null.

Comment: I think you should use assert in this case. Check the updated answer.